# How do I replace the obsolete Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.Configure method in my Unity solution?

Tags: unity-container

I have a Unity application that is running and working perfectly but we are currently in the process of cleaning up our code by acting on all the compilation warnings.

I get a warning on the following piece of code because of the obsolete Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.Configure method:

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = GetConfigFolderForFile("unity.config") };
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)config.GetSection(SectionName);

if (section != null)
{

    var container = new UnityContainer();

    foreach (ContainerElement containerElement in section.Containers)
    {
        containerElement.Configure(container);
    }

    Container = container; // Set the main container
}
```

I'd like to replace it with the UnityConfigurationSection.Configure method as suggested but can't see that they are equivalent because of being at different levels of the object hierarchy.

I've tried:

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = GetConfigFolderForFile("unity.config") };
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)config.GetSection(SectionName);

if (section != null)
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    container = section.Configure(container);

    Container = container; // Set the main container
}
```

but that falls down with null references.

How should I be updating the code to eliminate use of the obsolete method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work.  The secret was using the overload of the Configure method that takes a container name to configure each container element:

```
foreach (ContainerElement containerElement in section.Containers)
{
    container = section.Configure(container, containerElement.Name);
}
```

So far this looks as if it's doing the same as the obsolete Container.Configure method was doing - everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If the  section in the config doesn't have a name, it takes it as default and you don't need to specify a name:

```xml
<containers>
  <container>
    <types>
      <type type="IObject" mapTo="Object" />
    </types>
  </container>
</containers>
```